# How to solve this integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty } {{ e^{-(a-b)x^4}\cos((c-d)x)}dx} $?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, improper-integrals, complex-integration, trigonometric-integrals

Any ideas of solving this integral of $$\int\limits_0^{\infty } {{ e^{-(a-b)x^4}\cos((c-d)x)}dx} $$

[Integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwcrf.png)

Comment: why $(a-b), (c-d)$?

Comment: Try expanding cos term in power series and integrate term by term.

Comment: Assuming $a-b> 0$, a computer algebra system reports this definite integral is $\frac{\Gamma \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) (c-d)^2 \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{5}{4},\frac{3}{2};\frac{(c-d)^4}{256 (a-b)}\right)}{32
   (a-b)^{3/4}}+\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \,
   _0F_2\left(;\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{(c-d)^4}{256
   (a-b)}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{a-b}}$.

Comment: Did you use Wolfram? @EricTowers

Comment: I did not use Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: At least it is definite, thanks. Could you please tell me the name of the program?

Comment: Mathematica 11.3.0.0 Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: Thank you very much!